# Can Microsoft Report (RDLC) be used to print from a Console Application

Tags: c#, printing, console, report

We currently have a report done in Crystal Reports that prints reports from a console application.  The report is never displayed on screen.  It simply prints the batch of reports from the data provided.   Because of some environmental issues with Crystal Reports, I have been looking at using Microsoft Report instead.

While I have been able to create a report in a console application, and attach it to the database, it does not appear to me to be any way to address the report programatically, let alone execute and print it.  Is this a correct assessment?

Comment: You don't mention a programming language. Are you asking for a way to do this by writing code? If so, please add a language tag.

Comment: Yes. Programatically.  C# is fine, as that is my preference.  But we use both C# and VB.

Comment: No, there must be a way to do it. If you can't reference the report programatically hoe have you create in the console app?

Answer (score 2):

Using Microsoft Report, you can load and export reports without using the report viewer.

Here's an example from MS using a LocalReport:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport(v=vs.80).aspx

You'll notice that while the example takes place in a button click event, it doesn't actually rely on any UI methods and will function equally well from a console application.

The same technique works with a ServerReport.

If you're using Sql Server Reporting Services, you can use the web services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) to do pretty much the same thing.

In each of these cases, you'd export the report to a format to one of the supported formats. There is probably more information available on the SSRS side, but a lot of the things it discusses will be applicable to the Microsoft Report stuff (for example, DeviceInfo settings are available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395.aspx)